# A smooth function satisfying these functional constraints

Tags: probability-distributions, functional-equations

I am looking for any function on a square $$f:[-1,1]\times [-1,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$$ with the following properties:

1. The function $f$ is as smooth as possible, e.g. differentiable almost everywhere.
2. The function $f$ is symmetric: $f(a,b) = f(b,a)$
3. Thinking of the values of $f$ as probabilities, negating both arguments "inverts" the result: $f(a,b) + f(-a,-b) = 1$.
4. Increasing an argument increases the result: $f(a + \Delta, b) \geq f(a,b)$
5. The function $f$ attains its maximum when both arguments do: $f(1,1) = 1$.
6. The function is a linear interpolation when either argument is zero: $f(0,a) = \frac{1+a}{2}$

---

Is there a simple instance of a function with this form?

What sorts of functions have this behavior?

How do you think about finding functions of this form?

Comment: Is the "inversion" you refer to in (3) additive or multiplicative? The fact that you are using addition suggests the former, but the fact that the result is $1$ rather than $0$ suggests the latter. Is there a typo here?

Comment: Also, perhaps you want the intervals in your domain definition to be closed rather than open. As written, $f(1,1)$ is undefined.

Comment: Thanks. The language was unclear; the so-called inversion is like the relationship between the probability of an event (p) and the probability of its complement (1-p).

Comment: Re: open intervals, in my first few attempts I originally had additional constraints which were not simultaneously satisfiable at $f(-1,1)$ --- the open intervals were a holdover from that. Since I think I've removed the offending properties in this version, I've closed the invervals now.

Comment: Some of those things (1,2,5) seem like they could be bezier curve tensor products (bezier surface). Not sure about the rest though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest function I can come up with is the following:

$$f(a,b)=
\begin{cases} 
      0 & a + b \leq -1 \\
      \frac{1+a+b}{2} & -1 < a + b < 1 \\
      1 & a + b \geq 1 
\end{cases}$$

[Here is a 3D graph](http://tube.geogebra.org/m/1431833) of $z=f(x,y)$. Of course, it is not differentiable on the two lines where the function definition changes.

Graphically, you can imagine making it smoother by "dulling" the edges. You just need the function to pass through [this skeleton](https://tube.geogebra.org/m/1431817), obey the appropriate symmetries (namely about the point $(0,0,0.5)$ for condition $3$ and about the plane passing through $x=y$ and the $z$-axis for condition $2$), and obey your non-decreasing condition.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another piecewise linear solution:

Write
$$f(x,y)={1\over2}\bigl((1+g(x,y)\bigr)$$
whereby the function $g$ is defined by
$$g(x,y):=\cases{x+y\quad&$(-x\leq y\leq 0)$ \cr x\quad&$(0\leq y\leq x)$ \cr}$$
in the sector $x\geq|y|$ and has the required symmetries. Here is a picture of the graph of $f$:

[image]